# Prove that the limit is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let be $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of natural numbers, so $a_{n-1}$ divides $a_{n},n\geq 2$ and $\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}\geq n-\frac{1}{n}, n\geq 2$.

Prove that $x_{n}=\frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+..+\frac{1}{a_{n}}$ is convergent and its limit is an irrational number.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you experienced with such problems, e.g., proving $e$ is an irrational number?

Comment: I know how to prove that the limit is irrational. But, first, I don't manage to prove that is convergent

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\geq n-\frac1n$ is a pretty strange condition to make; since the ratio of consecutive terms is an integer (because of divisibility), we just as well could have said simply $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\geqslant n$. That being said, $a_n\geqslant n!$, which ensures convergence.

As for the irrationality, the proof goes like [that for $e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational#Fourier.27s_proof), except that we have $a_n$'s instead of factorials, which introduces a minor complication. Indeed, suppose the limit ($x$) is a rational number $p\over q$. Then let's look at $q\cdot a_{q^2}\cdot(x-x_{q^2})$: it is positive and must be an integer, yet it equals
$$q\cdot\left({a_{q^2}\over a_{q^2+1}}+{a_{q^2}\over a_{q^2+2}}+\dots\right)\leqslant q\cdot\left({1\over q^2}+{1\over q^4}+\dots\right)={q\over q^2-1}\color{red}{\bf<1}$$ which makes a contradiction.